# Php autocomplete with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make autocomplete with php array and jquery autocomplete function.
My code creates array in separate php script and it stores the array in session global variable. Then in the main script I have a form and a jquery function  that uses autocomplete but it doesn't work I tried it with a static array and it worked but when I try it with a dynamic array it doesn't work and I would like your help on how to do it so it will work.

index.php

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    $tags = $_SESSION['autocomplete'];
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form id="autocom" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
     <fieldset>
        <legend>Search</legend>
        <input id="auto" type="text" name="search">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
     </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var availableTags =  <?php echo json_encode($tags); ?>;
        console.log(availableTags);
            $( "#autocom" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

search.inc.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $dir = '../.';
    $a = scandir($dir);

    $searchQuery = $_GET['q'];

    $arr = array("<", ">", "!DOCTYPE", "html", "head", "body", "div", "table", "tr", "th", "td", "php", "?");
    $foundQueries = array();


    foreach ($a as $value) {
            if (strpos($value, ".php")) {
                $find = "../".$value;
                if (stripos(file_get_contents($find), $searchQuery) && !in_array($searchQuery, $arr)) {
                    $tagname = 'p';
                    $pattern = "#<\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*>(.*?)</$tagname\b[^>]*>#s";
                    preg_match_all($pattern, file_get_contents($find), $matches);
                    print_r($matches);
                    echo $value;
                    foreach ($matches as $pending) {
                        foreach ($pending as $found) {
                            if (stripos($found, $searchQuery)) {
                                $endFound = str_replace("<p>", "", $found);
                                $foundQueries[$value][] = str_replace("</p>", "", $endFound);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    echo '<xmp>';
                    print_r($foundQueries);
                    echo '</xmp>';
                    $_SESSION['autocomplete'] = $foundQueries;
                }
            }
        }
 ?>
```

Comment: _"Does not work"_ can mean anything. Please be more specific. If it works with a static array, the error is somewhere in your php. Do you get any errors? If not, debug the script. See if `$a = scandir($dir);` gives a result, then test `if (strpos($value, ".php"))`, then `preg_match_all(..)`, then `if (stripos($found, $searchQuery)) ` etc.

Comment: What does "it doesnt work" mean? What happens? What did you expect? Is the generated sourcecode of your javascript like you expected?

Comment: By "it doesnt work" I mean when I start typing in input I don't get any suggestions while using array from my php script but if Im using a static array I declare in index.php I get a autocomplete div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery you should be targeting the input element not the form.

Change `$( "#autocom" ).autocomplete({` to `$( "#auto" ).autocomplete({`.

Comment: Yes I see I made a typo I did change that now but it stil doesn't work

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(availableTags);`? It should be a one dimensional array. Otherwise you may have to map the values. Also inspect your code and check whether the echo command is outputting the desired results.

Comment: Object
citalci_vlom.php
:
Array(4)
0
:
"ARP Card"
1
:
"ARP Finger"
2
:
"ARP Finger Card"
3
:
"ARP Finger Key"
length
:
4
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object            
this is my object

Comment: your output seems to be the issue here, this what the output code should be `print_r( json_encode(['item1', 'item2', 'item3']));`

Comment: figured it out and made it differently, and it works quite alright